# Serialize custom ternary search tree in java

Tags: java, dictionary, ternary-search-tree

I would like to convert a dictionary of words into a binary file.
after some search time, I found out that ternary search tree is the best option for my usage.
I couldn't find how to serialize it to a file. 
Each node will have a char value, 3 pointers (for three children - low,equal,high) and another field (for saving other information)
How can I serialize it?
Thanks

Comment: recursively and with lots of love. Seriously, where are you stuck? And why can't you just put a list of strings into a file?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I need to use as less space as I can get, so I would like to serialize the tree into binary and then deserialize it

Comment: Traditional answer would be to have the tree, and every object in it, implement `Serializable`. Then just write it out with an ObjectOutputStream. That simplifies the problem to one object at a time.